# z-index is not working even though position absolute is mentioned?

Tags: z-index

I'm trying to put  overlay on top of showcase image and putting back texts on image  on top of overlay using `z-index`, but `z-index: 1` is not working. Position absolute is added and then `z-index:1` to create overlay effect but nothing is happening. Can someone check, what's going on here?
I have set position absolute and given its top ,left position for overlay

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 > <span class="coral">Acme</span> Web Design</h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                        <li >
                            <a class="coral" href="#"> HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"> ABOUT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"> SERVICES</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>


        <section id="showcase">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing         
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>

        

    </body>
    </html>
```

```
.container{
    width:80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header{
    background-color: #35424a;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 45px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid coral;
}

header ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


header li{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px ;


}


header h2{
    float: left;
}


header nav{
    float:right;
}

header h2{
    margin: 0;
}
.coral{
    color:coral;
}



#showcase{
    background-image: url("images/showcase2.jpg");
    background-position: center right;
    min-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    
    
}

#showcase::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:68px;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color: rgba(78, 89, 107, 0.6);
        

}

#showcase {

z-index:1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It got solved now. Z-index need to be added on container class which contains h2 and p tags.

```
#showcase{
    position: relative;
background-image:url("images/showcase.jpg") ; 
background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center right;
    min-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}




#showcase::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color: rgba(78, 89, 107, 0.8);

}

.container{
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: If this has solved your own question you should consider mark this as the answer so everyone can see it's solved.